# Select last XML node

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML code:

```
<AriaGostarInformation>
  <MenuInformation>
    <MenuNames Name="0" href="default.aspx">home</MenuNames>
    <SubMenuNames parentName="1">
      fgfgfgfgs
    </SubMenuNames>
    <SubMenuNames parentName="3">
    </SubMenuNames>
  </MenuInformation>
  <SliderInformation>
    <SliderImageAddress>..\..\Img\Hydrangeas.jpg,</SliderImageAddress>
    <SliderImageAddress>..\..\Img\Jellyfish.jpg,</SliderImageAddress>
    <SliderImageAddress>..\..\Img\Koala.jpg,</SliderImageAddress>
    <SliderImageAddress>..\..\Img\Lighthouse.jpg,</SliderImageAddress>
    <SliderImageAddress>..\..\Img\Penguins.jpg,</SliderImageAddress>
    <SliderImageAddress>..\..\Img\Tulips.jpg,</SliderImageAddress>
  </SliderInformation>
  <LastProductInformation>
    <Product Name="147">
      <Subject>
      </Subject>
      <ProductImageAddress>http://localhost:1209/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/Hydrangeas.jpg</ProductImageAddress>
      <ProductDes>
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="color:#FFA07A;"&gt;qwqweqweqe&lt;/span&gt;qwe&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:11px;"&gt;qweqweqw&lt;/span&gt;e&lt;/p&gt;
      </ProductDes>
    </Product>
    <Product Name="dsa">
      <Subject>salm</Subject>
      <ProductImageAddress>http://localhost:1209/ckeditor/plugins/imagebrowser/browser/Hydrangeas.jpg</ProductImageAddress>
      <ProductDes>
        &lt;p&gt;sdADASDASDASDASDASDASD&lt;/p&gt;

        &lt;p&gt;ASDASDASDADASDASDASDASDA&lt;/p&gt;

        &lt;p&gt;ASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASDASD&lt;/p&gt;
      </ProductDes>
    </Product>
  </LastProductInformation>
</AriaGostarInformation>
```

I want select last `product` node in `LastProductInformation` and get this node's attribute.
My code is:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\static\css\xml\data.xml");
XmlNode xparent = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//LastProductInformation");
var b = xparent.SelectSingleNode("/Product[last()]").Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

but this returns null. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
var value = XDocument.Load("path")
                      .Descendants("Product")
                      .Last()
                      .Attribute("Name").Value;
```

Also you can use `XPath` with `LINQ to XML`

```
var value = XDocument.Load("path")
             .XPathSelectElement("//LastProductInformation/Product[last()]")
             .Attribute("Name").Value;
```

**Note:** Make sure you have a reference to `System.Xml.Linq` namespace from your project.

Comment: i used your code but get this error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user3243749 could you update your question with the code that you are using currently? I have tried this code with your xml document and both of them worked

Comment: var value = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\static\css\xml\data.xml").XPathSelectElement("//LastProductInformation/Product[last()]").Attribute("Name").Value;

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code.Make sure your **path** is correct

Comment: @user3243749 did you try the first solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change to linq.

```
var b = xparent.SelectSingleNode("//Product")[last()].Attributes["Name"].Value;
```

The `last()` works like an index so should be at the end.